# my jquery code does not show any response. can anyone figure wats going wrong

Tags: jquery

Hi i am new to jQuery and was drawn by much of enthusiasm to learn it. But the problem in very first stage inhibits me from proceeding :(

this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
jQuery(".someclass").css("border","1px solid red");
jQuery("#si").html("so bold"); // (inside bold tags, cuz this editor s processing the      bold tag in my text )
}
)
```

I ve included a div of class someclass and another div of id si.

But i dont find any response here. can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: i have addedd the jquery library from googleapis

Comment: nope... there is no error error. my page simply loads.

Comment: Make sure you are loading jQuery first and then your script.

Comment: yes st3, i hav included the query first and then only the script. the line including the external jquery library is given first

Comment: Hello @CHID can you post your Entire code in this question ..so that we can solve much better;

Comment: <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.someclass{
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    jQuery(".someclass").css("border","1px solid red");
    jQuery("#si").html("<b>so bold</b>");
    }
    )

var jQuery=function(selector,context)
{
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="someclass">
hi
</div>
<div id="si">

</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Chid - where are you closing your first script tag?

Comment: it is actually closed karim, it is not being displayed here..

Comment: @ALL: thank you veyr much for your immediate response. The problem was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside your `$(document).ready(function()`:

```
alert($('.content') instanceof jQuery);
```

If that fires, and returns true, then jQuery is working and the problem is likely to be a selector/element mismatch.

Comment: hi karim, it is giving an alert saying false

Comment: It is probably because are not closing your first script tag: `<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/"></script>`

Comment: when i removed that function selector,context it is giving an alert true and the jquery works fine. I saw tht code from a tutorial. but i dunt know why this is happening..

Comment: Also try to put a try.. catch inside your code, to catch exceptions and print them out.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a local copy of jquery temporarily instead of the Google CDN version, you will be able to debug the calls and see if they are actually firing and also whether they are finding the elements you are searching for.

Cheers,

Ed

Comment: thank yu ed, there was a mistake in my code which included a function.. and now its fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the missing semicolon in the end (it shouldn't be, but at least it might help isolating the error). I know the whole thing looks like a function declaration but it's actually a call.

Also you can use shorthands for jQuery, document-ready, etc. The less code you write, the less room for mistakes there is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".someclass").css("border","1px solid red");
    $("#si").html("so bold");
});
```